# Pulling a list of AD users based on attributes in a CSV?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to use values in a CSV file as the variable in a `Get-ADUser` command.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$users = Import-Csv "C:\path\users.csv"

ForEach ($user in $users)
Get-ADUser -Filter { $user.sAmAccountName -SearchBase "ou=OU1,OU=OU2,DC=DC1,DC=DC2" }
```

The CSV has a header for samAccountName.

The error I'm getting is

```
Get-ADUser : Error parsing query: '$user' Error Message: 'syntax error'
```

Comment: If you have the sAMAccountName in your CSV file you should use the parameter `-Identtity` instead of `-Filter` and you don't need a `-SearchBase` then.

Comment: That was it! I'm cleanly returning user objects with that change alone. Thank you so much!

Comment: Quick note - to make the code fences work properly, they should be put on a line of their own, see [Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for more details. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd point out a few additional issues:

With respect to the AD cmdlets `-Filter` parameter argument should be a string not a script block.  You can observe this in the help documentation.  You can specify a script block and the cmdlet will convert it to a string, but that sometimes presents complications.

You are better off specifying the argument like:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "$($user.sAmAccountName) -SearchBase 'ou=OU1,OU=OU2,DC=DC1,DC=DC2'"
```

That said, in this particular case you do not need the `ForEach(..){..}` loop. You can use property unrolling to simply pipe the samAccountName to `Get-ADUser` :

```
$Users.samAccountName | Get-ADUser
```

This will not work in conjunction with the `-SearchBase` parameter, but I believe samAccountName is unique and should work in this manner.  This is also true of using the `-Identity` parameter as discussed.  In fact, the piped approach is equivalent to the suggested use of `-Identity` parameter, the piped objects are bound to `-Identity`. However, you cannot site the array, unrolled or otherwise, as a directly specified argument to the `-Identity` parameter.